# PHP APC Configuration shm_size

Tags: php, mysql, caching, cron, apc

I am about to use PHP APC for the first time but im not sure on the configuration settings.

I am using a apache VPS server with 32GB ram 12-cores, Varnish, and storing static files on Amazon S3.

And running on the server is my php/mysql application.

But would setting **apc.shm_size** to 1024M be too much? Using 1gb of my 32gb.

Also, would it be a good idea to run a cron-job each day, Eg 5am to clear the cache?
so the cache doesnt become fragmented.

Here are my settings:

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=1024M
apc.cache_by_default="1"
apc.shm_segments="1"
apc.ttl="7200"
apc.user_ttl="7200"
apc.gc_ttl="1800"
apc.optimization = 0
apc.num_files_hint="1024"
apc.use_request_time = 1
apc.mmap_file_mask="/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.enable_cli="0"
apc.slam_defense="0"
apc.file_update_protection="2"
apc.max_file_size="1M"
apc.stat="1"
apc.write_lock="1"
apc.report_autofilter="0"
apc.include_once_override="0"
apc.rfc1867="0"
apc.rfc1867_prefix="upload_"
apc.rfc1867_name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
apc.rfc1867_freq="0"
apc.localcache="0"
apc.localcache.size="512"
apc.coredump_unmap="0"
```

And my cron-job which I would use everyday 5am:

```
<?php
if (in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1')))
{
  apc_clear_cache();
  apc_clear_cache('user');
  apc_clear_cache('opcode');
  echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
}
else
{
  die('Not c');
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using APC for anything other than opcode caching?

Comment: Why not leave it something like apc.shm_size=128M until you're certain that you need more?

Comment: Note that Webserver APC and CLI APC aren't shared; each CLI task runs its own APC, and can't talk to the Webserver APC; so a cron job won't do anything to clear the webserver's APC cache

Comment: And as you have `apc.enable_cli="0"`, you'll achieve even less running a cron task unless that cron task executes a curl request to a web-based cleardown script

Comment: Or is it safe to just restart my apache server in order to clear the cache without having to use any APC functions.
Eg:  "sudo service apache2 restart"

Comment: restarting apache will clear both opcode and user APC webserver cache

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answers Mark. I will prob just restart apache then. So I can make sure it clears fine.